# PlotHighlighting - Option

Tags: plotting, legending

```
data = <|
"exp" -> <|15 -> 1419, 16 -> 1454, 17 -> 1526, 18 -> 1560, 19 -> 1579, 20 -> 1433, 21 -> 1572, 22 -> 1625|>, 
"imp" -> <|15 -> 1190, 16 -> 1243, 17 -> 1308, 18 -> 1360, 19 -> 1399, 20 -> 1280, 21 -> 1395, 22 -> 1491|>
|>;

ListLinePlot[data,
 LabelingFunction -> None,
 PlotLabels -> Automatic,
 PlotMarkers -> All,
 PlotHighlighting -> "Ball"]
```

[image]

I have two requests:

1. The `Ball`- box should only display if the mouse pointer is on or 
   close to one of the `PlotMarkers`
2. The `PlotLabels` ("exp" or "imp") should also appear inside the 
   `Ball`- box

Comment: Do you only want the `Ball` to show up for the point closest to the mouse pointer, or the whole set of points when the mouse is close to one of the points? I can kind of get the latter to work with `Mouseover`, but am having trouble figuring out how to do the first one.

Comment: Only the point closest to the mouse pointer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
labelingRules = Join @@ KeyValueMap[Thread[#2 -> #] &] @ 
    Map[KeyValueMap[List]] @ data;

plotHighlighting = {{"IndicatedPoint", <|"Style" -> AbsolutePointSize[12]|>}, 
   {"XYLabel", <|Appearance -> None,  
     LabelingFunction -> 
       (Row[{#[[All, 1]] /. labelingRules, Splice@#}, ","] &)|>}};


ListLinePlot[data, PlotLabels -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> All, 
 PlotHighlighting -> plotHighlighting]
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to also show the x- and y-values? For example, "exp, 20, 1280" .

Comment: @eldo, please see the updated version.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, maybe?

I'm not partial to the `Association`, so:

```
data2 = {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Normal[#] & /@ {data[[1]], data[[2]]}
```

> {{{15, 1419}, {16, 1454}, {17, 1526}, {18, 1560}, {19, 1579}, {20,
> 1433}, {21, 1572}, {22, 1625}}, {{15, 1190}, {16, 1243}, {17,
> 1308}, {18, 1360}, {19, 1399}, {20, 1280}, {21, 1395}, {22, 1491}}}

```
labels = Keys[data]
```

> {"exp", "imp"}

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Tooltip[#, labels[[n]] <> " " <> ToString[#]] & /@ 
   data2[[n]], {n, 2}], PlotMarkers -> All]
```

[image]

Edited to add a `PlotHighlighting` option (but I couldn't figure out how to add custom text to the labels)

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotLabels -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> All, 
 PlotHighlighting -> {"IndicatedPoint", "XYLabel"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does what I want - but I hoped that I could do it with the `PlotHighlighted` - option (because it offers more options than `Tooltip`, marker lines for example).

Comment: @eldo I added something with `PlotHighlighting`, but I could not figure out how to add "exp" etc to the labels.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: pre-process input data wrapping each data set with [`Highlighted`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Highlighted.html):

```
highlightingF[key_] :=    
  {{"IndicatedPoint", <|"Style" -> AbsolutePointSize[12]|>}, 
   {"XYLabel", <|Appearance -> None, 
     LabelingFunction -> (Row[{key, Splice@#}, ","] &)|>}};

toHighlightedData = Association @*
   KeyValueMap[{k, v} |-> k -> Highlighted[v, highlightingF[k]]];

ListLinePlot[toHighlightedData @ data, 
 PlotLabels -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: To use other `Highlight`- options: Change `ListLinePlot` to `ListPlot` with `Joined->True` and `IndicatedPoint` to f.e. `Dropline`